What are the mechanical differences between difficulty levels in Flintlock: Siege of Dawn?
When Flintlock: Siege of Dawn was announced, some amount of journalistic ink was spilled over how it had difficulty settings, making it more of a Souls-lite over a Souls-like. Now that we have a playable demo and will soon have the full game, we can see that the game does indeed have "Story", "Normal", and "Punishing" difficulty levels.
Unfortunately, there isn't much information given on what the different difficulty settings actually do. According to the demo version, Story difficulty turns off achievements, but little else is given about the changes in gameplay that result from Story or Punishing mode.
What differences in gameplay do the different difficulty settings add in?

I'm interested in basic combat changes, like adjustments to damage taken by player and damage dealt by player.
I'm also interested in more subtle gameplay changes--are dodge and parry windows affected by the difficulty settings, or the buildup of Enki's Death Curse "prime" bar?
Are reputation (xp) amounts or combat multipliers adjusted by difficulty setting?

